# Is there an equivalent for continue(java) in python 3.0

Tags: java, python

I would like to use a function that would skip the loop for one iteration. I found out that continue works in Java,  but it doesn't seem to work in Python. Is there an equivalent of continue in Python, and if so, what is it?

Comment: `continue` works fine in Python. You did something wrong.

Comment: The [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops) says there is a `continue` in 2.7 and 3.6. Maybe this is why nobody ever uses your 3.0.

Comment: Can we see your code, `continue` should work.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Refer to the official python [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops) for information on continue in python.